# German word "Aufhocker"

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the word "Aufhocker"? Is this word commonly used today? Anything interesting to say about this word?

Comment: You should tell us where you found the word.

Comment: Since @infinitezero did give the context in his answer, I don't consider it necessary to close for *needs clarity*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never heard the word before, so [I had to look it up](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Aufhocker).

> Geist, der dem einsamen Wanderer von hinten auf die Schulter springt, ihn würgt u. niederdrückt
>   *Ghost that jumps on the back/shoulder of a lonely wanderer that strangles him/pushes him down*

[It is referenced in folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiederg%C3%A4nger)

The word comes from the verb *hocken* (to crouch/squat/sit). A person who "hocks" can be referred to as a *Hocker* (although quite unconventional). Together with the word *auf* (here: on top of something), *Aufhocker* gets the meaning of "somebody who gets on somebody/something and sits/squats on top of it".

Comment: Unconventional? suppose the *Stubenhocker* really is a double entendre describing a person as a piece of furniture (not to say *Möbel-Stück*). That was my first association as a child, indeed.

Comment: by the way, cp English *hug*. A person who *hugs* can be described as *anhänglich*, viz *Klammeraffe*, etc. Also *choke*, in the same sense. I'm saying the allusion to *hocken* "squat" may be accidental. However, *aufgesessen* (einem Irrtum aufgesessen ~ getäuscht worden), *besessen* (see *possessed*) compare well, except that *sitzen* is extremely polysemous so no good indication. Google offers aufhocken among translations for aufsitzen 2 auf ein Motorad aufsteigen -- so it seems to be not totally obscure.

Comment: I meant the word by itself. You rarely (if ever) call a person a "Hocker". Stubenhocker as a compositum is much more common, I agree.

Comment: cp perhaps also *to hike*, whence I like to derive *hooker* (prostitute waiting on the way side, walking the line). Also compare *sich irgendwo einhaken*. PS: small correction, google said 1.b auf ein Fahrzeug aufsteigen, and 1.a auf ein Pferd ... which puts things into perspective for *aufsteigen*.